# svg icon not coloring correctly on hover

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add social media icons, they should turn purple on hover. Unfortunately, on hover, a part of the icon is painted wrong (the entire circle is painted, although this should not be). [screenshot of what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snWiz.png) and [what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flnxN.png)

I use tailwind in my project. In the class of added images I used `className='fill-current hover:fill-primary-500'`. Stroke is also don't work

```js
const socials = [
  {
    icon: (
      <IcFB
        className='hover:fill-primary-500'
        width={40}
        height={40}
      />
    ),
    title: 'Facebook',
    url: '#',
  },
  {
    icon: (
      <IcInstagram
        className='hover:fill-primary-500'
        width={40}
        height={40}
      />
    ),
    title: 'Instagram',
    url: '#',
  },
]

const Socials: FC = observer(() => {
  return (
    <div className='flex space-x-4'>
      {socials.map((s) => (
        <LinkWrapper key={s.url} href={s.url} title={s.title} target='_blank'>
          {s.icon}
        </LinkWrapper>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please show your code (in [mcve] form, ideally as runnable snippet if possible), so that folks can see what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const socials = [
  {
    icon: (
      <IcFB
        className='fill-primary-500 hover:fill-white'
        width={40}
        height={40}
      />
    ),
    title: 'Facebook',
    url: '#',
  },
  {
    icon: (
      <IcInstagram
        className='fill-primary-500 hover:fill-white'
        width={40}
        height={40}
      />
    ),
    title: 'Instagram',
    url: '#',
  },
]

const Socials: FC = observer(() => {
  return (
    <div className='flex space-x-4'>
      {socials.map((s) => (
        <LinkWrapper key={s.url} href={s.url} title={s.title} target='_blank'>
          {s.icon}
        </LinkWrapper>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
})
```